# what's the difference between a and $a in assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, att

In intel assembly 86-84 (AT&T) what's the difference between:

```
imul $4, a, %eax
```

and:

```
imul $4, $a, %eax
```

and:

```
imul $4, (a), %eax # Sometimes I see braces around registers too, what is their job?
```

where a is a variable in memory declared like this:

```
.section .data 
a: .int 0x2
```

Comment: Have you tried reading the GNU as manual?  It has a brief introduction to the syntax.

Comment: I read but still I am confused between the three I am not settled on this one

Comment: `$a` is an immediate, absence of the `$` indicates a memory operand.  Registers in parentheses indicate index registers.

Comment: what if it is $garbage_address?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.  That would still be an immediate.

Comment: `imul $4, $a, %eax` is an error; IMUL can't take two immediate operands.  Do `mov $a * 4, %eax` to do math at assemble time, but that only works if `a` is a .equ constant, not a label, because the assembler + linker don't support multiplying an address by 4.

Comment: @fuz you are wrong, it's the pointer to it

Comment: @john The addressing mode is “immediate” as in “the operand is this value.”